# Alternative to flotchart jquery lib

Tags: library, javascript, charts

I am looking at a more recent and **modern chart js library** than *flot*.

My problem with *flot* is that it does not support well mobile and tablet. At the last resort, I will have to use myself *hammer.js* to code something. But if that would come built-in or with some plugin with another library, that would be nice.

- I tried **chart.js**, and it is slow to render my data (which are not that huge). Zooming is slow. I don't know if there is something to configure here. Panning does not work. I can't find help to debug this. No IRC, no forum.
- I tried **taucharts**. Which is huge in size, coming with d3. And very slow to render my data. I did not see anything to zoom or pan, yet. May be I have not looked well.
- I tried **echarts**. But I couldn't make it work I don't know why. I got an error and I can't debug this. My fault here.

So I am looking for something as lightweight as possible coming with zoom/pan built-in or with plugin.

Comment: If you think taucharts is took large, because it s based on d3, then you probably won't accept [D3js](https://d3js.org/), which is a pity as it the best there is

Comment: It's not that I mind d3, but bare d3.js seems a whole framework or language to learn and master. Quite a beast, it seems. I just have a line plot and a bar chart to draw and update.

Comment: Ah, now I undestand. Learning curve. Well, there are certainly simpler libraries. OTOH, d3hs has plenty of examples & dcoumentation. I just copied & altered. If there is even a slim chance that you might want to use some of [those tempting baubles](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery), then you may as well jump right in now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Syncfusion provides a chart control [ejChart](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/chart/defaultfunctionalities) that works with jQuery. The chart is responsive and can be used on mobile and tablet devices.
Zooming and Panning are [built in.](https://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/chart/userinteraction/zoomingandpanning)

[image: Syncfusion ejChart with zooming and panning]

There is also a newer chart control [EJ2 Chart](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.3.17-beta/demos/#/material/chart/line.html) that is not jQuery depedendent. The chart is responsive and can be used on mobile and tablet devices and also has better performance and is lightweight.
Zooming and Panning are [built in.](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.3.17-beta/demos/#/material/chart/zooming.html)

[image: Syncfusion EJ2 Chart with zooming and panning]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=srecs39882) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.